# Reading battery value from bios using applescript

Tags: macos, dos, power-management, bios

How can I get the battery status/level using applescript?

Is it possible?

Can anyone provide a code snippet?

My battery kext is not working so I need some direct info from hardware.

Comment: this is probably going to depend on the os you are using.

Comment: What's wrong with ACPI ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get battery info directly from BIOS.

There are different ways to it:

- [use WMI](http://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmi/vbscript/0046/);
- read information directly from battery. To do it you need to implement i2c (smbus) protocol and gain access to southbridge. This IC contains SMBus controller in PC. And battery is connected to it by SMBus.

Also please take a look to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372659.aspx)